# Error : Cannot write configuration file

Tags: c#, iis, razor

I tried running my Razor Website And IIS Threw this error. It has been a while since i ran it so i am totally lost as to what the error could be. Any help would to great

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ujsS.png)

This is my startup.cs file

```
namespace NewsReader1
{

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
            }
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you check if the filename is correct? Seems like you want to access your hard drive but the path starts with "\\". Also check if you have permission to write on the directory.

Comment: I experienced this as a OneDrive issue when files on demand is enabled.  Are you using the latest VS/OneDrive client?

Comment: Please use a source control system like Git to keep your source files, instead of OneDrive, which can lock your files any time it likes, and break other tools, like VS.

Comment: @AlexK Yes i am using the latest VS / OneDrive client .